# dependency inversion implementation in javascript

Tags: javascript, dependency-inversion

the book "Clean Architecture" said:

> When using dynamically typed languages like Ruby and Python ... dependency inversion does not require either the declaration or the inheritance of interfaces.

but I don't quite understand it, the book didn't provide any example

my understanding of the DIP is that if ClassA depends on ClassB violating the DIP, we can introduce an InterfaceC, then we get something like

```
ClassA ---> InterfaceC <--- ClassB
```

I've also looked at some examples on the internet, like this one that attempts dependency injection between `PurchaseHandler` and `PayPal`
, https://duncan-mcardle.medium.com/solid-principle-5-dependency-inversion-javascript-7b054685f7cb

```js
class PurchaseHandler {
    processPayment(paymentDetails, amount) {
        const paymentSuccess = PaymentHandler.requestPayment(
            paymentDetails,
            amount
        );

        if (paymentSuccess) {
            // Do something
            return true;
        }

        // Do something
        return false;
    }
}

class PaymentHandler {
    requestPayment(paymentDetails, amount) {
        // Complicated, PayPal specific logic goes here
        return PayPal.requestPayment(paymentDetails, amount);
    }
}
```

However, it seems to simply add a layer between them, resulting in this dependency graph:

```
PurchaseHandler ---> PaymentHandler ---> PayPal
```

no inversion is happening here...

=== update Mar 15th, 2024 ===
it's true that the above example doesn't work because of the language syntax...

finally, I got the answer from this youtube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9oHY5TllWaU

in js, it's similar to the Facade design pattern

Comment: I doubt the above posted code would work at all. First, `requestPayment` is a prototypal method and not a static one of class `PaymentHandler`. Yet the also prototypal `processPayment` method of `PurchaseHandler` does forward the payment handling to `PaymentHandler.requestPayment`, hence invoking a static method that does not exist. It rather should be `paymentHandler.requestPayment` where `paymentHandler` is an instance of `PaymentHandler` and has been aggregated as part of any `PurchaseHandler` instance. The same applies to the forwarding `PayPal.requestPayment` invocation.

Answer (score 0):

You must have in mind that interfaces are not supported in JavaScript. The point of interfaces in clean architecture is that the Class A must depend on a method from Class B but it does not matter how the method is implemented. This allows you to make changes on Class B without affecting Class A. The interface only ensures that the method from Class B exists not the way it is implemented.

In your example, the class PurchaseHandler depends on a Class PaymentHandler but it doesn't matter if you use PayPal or another payment method. You can change the payment method with out rewriting the class PurchaseHandler. This way, the Dependency inversion principle is accomplished.

If you want to do it in a more pure way in javascript, you should use inheritance:

PurchaseHandler -> PaymentHandler_Child <- PaymentHandler_Parent

The class PaymentHandler_Parent must have a method requestPayment but must return an error or something else unexpected. Then using inheritance, you must implement in class PaymentHandler_Child the payment in a method called requestPayment. In this way, you are obliged to implement this method as if it were an interface in another programing language. The class PurchaseHandler, must call the method implemented in PaymentHandler_Child.